# how to get eclipse location? not workspace

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

eclipse 4.7.2 oxygen plugin develope.
I want to get eclipse launcher path. no workspace path.

Eclipse > Help > About Eclipse > Details > Configuration

-launcer 
c:\eclipse\eclipse.exe

how to get this path?

Answer (score 1):

You probably want the install location:

```java
import org.eclipse.core.runtime.Platform;
import org.eclipse.osgi.service.datalocation.Location;
import java.net.URL;


Location loc = Platform.getInstallLocation();
URL installURL = loc.getURL();
```